# Obtener el tiempo de un vídeo con VLCJ

Tags: java, vlcj

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual reproduzco un vídeo e itero el movimiento de una boca mediante la lectura de un fichero. Estoy usando **VLCJ** para la reproducción del vídeo y estoy intentando obtener la duración del vídeo que reproduzco pero cuando lo hago me retorna un `-1`.

```
long duracionVideo = ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().getLength();
```

He probado en vez de `getLength()` con `getTime()` pero aún así me sigue retornando `-1`.

¿Alguien sabe como podría obtener la duración del vídeo?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo

Comment: El vídeo que intentas reproducir, lo tienes almacenado en local o está en remoto (En otro ordenador o servidor)?

Comment: Lo tengo almacenado en local

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void finished (MediaPlayer mediaplayer){
                //Codigo que quieres que ejecute
            }
        });
```